# JOIN Call table to grouping by Origination and Destination

Tags: mysql, join, query

[image: Call system]

### It's a call system.

#### tables structure and data sample :

**tbl_countries**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_countries
(
    country_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    country varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO tbl_countries (country) VALUES ('Austria');
INSERT INTO tbl_countries (country) VALUES ('Brazil');
INSERT INTO tbl_countries (country) VALUES ('Denmark');
INSERT INTO tbl_countries (country) VALUES ('France');
INSERT INTO tbl_countries (country) VALUES ('Lebanon');
```

**tbl_destination_clients**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_destination_clients
(
    des_client_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    des_client varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    country_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tbl_destination_clients_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES tbl_countries (country_id)
);
CREATE INDEX country_id ON tbl_destination_clients (country_id);
INSERT INTO tbl_destination_clients (des_client, country_id) VALUES ('961123456', 5);
INSERT INTO tbl_destination_clients (des_client, country_id) VALUES ('55123456', 2);
INSERT INTO tbl_destination_clients (des_client, country_id) VALUES ('45123456', 3);
```

**tbl_origination_clients**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_origination_clients
(
    orig_client_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    orig_client varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    country_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tbl_origination_clients_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES tbl_countries (country_id)
);
CREATE INDEX country_id ON tbl_origination_clients (country_id);
INSERT INTO tbl_origination_clients (orig_client, country_id) VALUES ('33123456', 4);
INSERT INTO tbl_origination_clients (orig_client, country_id) VALUES ('43123456', 1);
```

**tbl_calls**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_calls
(
    call_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    orig_client_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    des_client_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    call_duration int(11) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tbl_calls_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (orig_client_id) REFERENCES tbl_origination_clients (orig_client_id),
    CONSTRAINT tbl_calls_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (des_client_id) REFERENCES tbl_destination_clients (des_client_id)
);
CREATE INDEX des_client_id ON tbl_calls (des_client_id);
CREATE INDEX orig_client_id ON tbl_calls (orig_client_id);
INSERT INTO tbl_calls (orig_client_id, des_client_id, call_duration) VALUES (1, 3, 5);
INSERT INTO tbl_calls (orig_client_id, des_client_id, call_duration) VALUES (1, 3, 6);
INSERT INTO tbl_calls (orig_client_id, des_client_id, call_duration) VALUES (2, 4, 9);
INSERT INTO tbl_calls (orig_client_id, des_client_id, call_duration) VALUES (1, 1, 10);
```

#### Attemps :

I try to use JOIN between the same table `tbl_calls`, like this :

```
select
  co.country Origination,
  cd.country Destination,
  sum(c.call_duration) TotalDuration
from tbl_calls c 
inner join tbl_destination_clients d on d.des_client_id = c.des_client_id
inner join tbl_origination_clients o on o.orig_client_id = c.des_client_id
inner join tbl_countries cd on cd.country_id = d.country_id
inner join tbl_countries co on co.country_id = o.country_id
group by   
  co.country,
  cd.country;
```

But it's not working ;(

The Result of this sample data must be :

```
Origination  Destination  SUM(call_duration)
------------+------------+----------------
France       Brazil       11 -> (5+6)
Austria      Denmark      9
France       Lebanon      10
```

Thanks ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change one join column on the `inner join` from `tbl_calls` to  `tbl_origination_clients`. You have currently `c.des_client_id` but it should be `c.orig_client_id`.

**Query with adapted join column**

```
select
  co.country Origination,
  cd.country Destination,
  sum(c.call_duration) TotalDuration
from tbl_calls c 
inner join tbl_destination_clients d on d.des_client_id = c.des_client_id
inner join tbl_origination_clients o on o.orig_client_id = c.orig_client_id
inner join tbl_countries cd on cd.country_id = d.country_id
inner join tbl_countries co on co.country_id = o.country_id
group by   
  co.country,
  cd.country;
```

**Result**

```
| Origination | Destination | TotalDuration |
| ----------- | ----------- | ------------- |
| Austria     | Denmark     | 9             |
| France      | Brazil      | 11            |
| France      | Lebanon     | 10            |
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5orK4BVCK8hs3ENoJm5ZbP/1)